# Cocoa Webview - only show a specific <div>

Tags: css, cocoa, macos, html, webview

This question is pretty simple - is it possible to only show a specific < div>s with specific id's in a WebView?  If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the view a `styleDeclarationWithText:` message to instantiate a style declaration for a style sheet like this:

```
div {
    display: none;
}
div#alice, div#bob, div#cthulhu {
    display: block;
}
```

and send the view an `applyStyle:` message, passing the style declaration object, to apply it.

Comment: Thanks, that seems so obvious!  My HTML and CSS skills have let me down!:P  Thanks, anyway!